# Why was this post deleted? Since when do we need citations to make Answers acceptable on WB?

Tags: discussion

What's the deal with [this Answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/32232/885)

It has a banner saying it needs more citations.  But this SE is all about making things up and discussing ideas, except for specific cases such as [hard-science](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-science).  It's had a ridiculous number of references added, so now it's basically a list of sources.  The apparently new user was told to post more of them.  Then the Answer was deleted.

What's the story here?

Comment: That's a good question, but you'll notice that on the edit history, the post only contained the first paragraph, which might need some backing up, and got deleted. The User then went on editing their post to add all the references. We could probably consider reopening it now, even if it needs a bit of clean up.

Comment: Even so, why would that one paragraph be deleted for need of citations?  We give off-the-cuff answers here all the time.

Comment: The post notice was added by Vincent, and the answer was subsequently deleted by community vote, long before any of the references were added. I have removed the post notice and undeleted the answer, but I'm leaving to Vincent to explain the reasoning behind adding the post notice. Absent a hard-science tag, one shouldn't have been needed (even though references is never a bad thing to add; all things equal, I'd almost certainly prefer an answer with references than one without). See [the answer's revision history](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/posts/32232/revisions).

Comment: @JDługosz I did seem like quite a wild claim, even for our standards.

Answer (score 3):

Since the notice is more than a month old, I will try to answer as best as I can but I've completely forgotten about this answer by now. Ideally, next time there is a problem, it would be better not to wait that much.

Now that the answer as been edited, I agree with you that it's just a list of references. Just one or two would have been enough.

I'm quoting the first version of the answer:

> Given that there are already intelligent birds (parrots, ravens,
>   magpies) with intellectual abilities akin to a human child, this
>   suggests that their brains are far better optimized than human brains,
>   weight for weight. So an avian brain of equivalent intellect to a
>   human adult would not necessarily have to weigh anywhere near 1.3 kg.

Problems I see with this answer (in the original state):

1. Birds are as intelligent as a human child. I'm not an expert in ornithology but I have serious doupt this claim. I don't doupt that birds have a certain level of intelligence, but saying they are just as intelligent as a child would require something more solid to back it up.
2. Their brains are more optimized: That's based on the assumption that 1 is true which still remain to be proved.

Also, as HDE already mentioned, the answer might prove that birds are intelligent, but I does not explain how they became intelligent.

- **Was it exaggerated to add a notice on the post?** I don't think so
  since it's just a warning. By the time I added the notice, there was already an active flag for **not an answer** and deletion was already under way. I added the notice hoping that it would help the user improve the post.

Answer (score 2):

I was one of the original people who voted to delete it, so I'll give my reasons.

The question was

> What could cause an avian species to become intelligent?

The original answer was

> Given that there are already intelligent birds (parrots, ravens, magpies) with intellectual abilities akin to a human child, this suggests that their brains are far better optimized than human brains, weight for weight. So an avian brain of equivalent intellect to a human adult would not necessarily have to weigh anywhere near 1.3 kg.

This does not answer the question at all. At all. Unless you think that it's disputing the premise of the question by saying that birds are already as intelligent as children, which is something of an odd claim.

This answer was originally posted on December 27, and was deleted on December 28. The sources were not added - in fact, the answer was not edited - until ~9 hours ago. The reason the user was told to post sources would have been because originally, *there were none*. Then the answer was deleted, long before any edits were made.

I stand by the decision to delete the answer in its old form. I don't think that the sources make the answer fantastic - while good research, it still doesn't address the "what could cause" part of the question - but it's not as bad now. My reaction to the undeletion is that the answer is borderline Not An Answer, but the answer is certainly better now, and it was certainly worse before.